# FEN Loader to Position giving off numbers

Tags: fen

So i tried to build a FEN loader that create a "Chess Board" in a array Square[8,8].

This is the code so far

```
public static void LoadPositionFromFen(string fen)
    {

        var PieceTypeFromSymbol = new Dictionary<char, int>()
        {
            ['K'] = Piecies.White.King,
            ['k'] = Piecies.Black.King,
            ['P'] = Piecies.White.Pawn,
            ['p'] = Piecies.Black.Pawn,
            ['N'] = Piecies.White.Knight,
            ['n'] = Piecies.Black.Knight,
            ['B'] = Piecies.White.Bishop,
            ['b'] = Piecies.White.Bishop,
            ['R'] = Piecies.White.Rook,
            ['r'] = Piecies.Black.Rook,
            ['Q'] = Piecies.White.Queen,
            ['q'] = Piecies.Black.Queen
        };
        string fenBoard = fen.Split(' ')[0];
        int rank = 0, file = 0;

        foreach (char symbol in fenBoard)
        {
            if (symbol == '/') {
                rank = 0;
                file++;
            } else
            {
                if (char.IsDigit(symbol))
                {
                    rank += (int) char.GetNumericValue(symbol);
                }
                else
                {
                    var piece = PieceTypeFromSymbol[symbol];
                    Square[rank, file] = piece;
                    rank++;
                }
                
            }
           
        }

    
}`
```

But then i try to look some of the piecies And i get this:

> 15 12 0 0 0 0 2 5

This is the value of every piece:

```
public class White
            {
            public const byte None = 0;
            public const byte King = 1;
            public const byte Pawn = 2;
            public const byte Knight = 3;
            public const byte Bishop = 4;
            public const byte Rook = 5;
            public const byte Queen = 6;
    }
    public class Black
    {
        public const byte None = 10;
        public const byte King = 11;
        public const byte Pawn = 12;
        public const byte Knight = 13;
        public const byte Bishop = 14;
        public const byte Rook = 15;
        public const byte Queen = 16;
    }
```

The numbers are completely off, as i checked for the squares, 0,0 0,1 0,2 0,3 0,4 0,5 06, 0,7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the dictionary White and Black Bishops are inverted.
File needs to be 7. (file = 7) and get decremented each '/' (file--)
And i was checking putting first the file and then the rank but i place piecies by `Square[rank,file]` = piece